# Getting an export from an MEF container given only a Type instance

Tags: c#, mef

I have a scenario where I have to get an export from my CompositionContainer instance but I only have a Type to work with; I don't know the type at compile time, hence I can't retrieve the exported object in the normal generic way.

Normally you would do this:

```
_container.GetExportedObject<IMyType>();
```

But in my case, I have this:

```
Type someType = ... ;
_container.HowDoIGetTheExport(someType);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
var export = _container.GetExports(someType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes that is the core method that most of the generic overloads use, so that is the best way to get it.

Comment: Don't forget the thing you seek is in export.Value

Answer (score 1):

Create the call dynamically using Type.MakeGeneric.....

[http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/03/24/109722.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200628093547/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/marcel/archive/2007/03/24/109722.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't help me call a generic method on the container... I don't think you read my question properly.

Comment: I see you have a specific answer - excellent. My answer is more general in the sense that from a Type you can construct a generic method call at run time. We use this to construct calls where only interfaces are know at compile time but running instances can be fed from external sources.